# Inject values from python script through console arguments

Tags: python, arguments

Change code to inject values through console arguments (python script)

In this moment i have adapted the code to inject the value that are defined through a json file which the script load and read, but i need to change this approach to read the value directly by arguments in the console, how can i do this?

Ex: "py login.py username: ' ' password: ' ' "

```
pyhton script code (login.py):

 with open(sys.argv[1]) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

 susername = data["log_username"]
 spassword = data["log_password"]

 log_username=susername
 log_password=spassword
```

json file:

```
"log_username": "blalala",
"log_password": "blalala",
```

Comment: it looks like you've almost got it already. if you pass in the username and password from the console, you can access them through `sys.argv` just as you are doing to read the path to the json file.

Comment: If you ran `py login.py username:'hello' password:'world'`, `sys.argv[1]` would be `username:'hello'`. You could split that on `:` and then remove the quotes from `'hello'`.

Comment: so i just need to remove the: as json_data, data = json.load(json_data)? i learning python i little while ago only and im bit still confuse whit the code..sorry